# ionic 3 storage clear after re open the browser

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, storage

i can read value from storage until app not close.
after i close the browser and re run the app. i'll get null value from storage.get

in tutorial page:

```
this.storage.set('hasSeenTutorial', 'true');
```

in component.ts:

```
this.storage.get('hasSeenTutorial')
.then((hasSeenTutorial) => {
  debugger;
  if (hasSeenTutorial) {
    this.selectRootPage();
  } else {
    this.rootPage = 'TutorialPage';
  }
  this.platformReady()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With ionic-3 its a known fact that the local storage gets cleared at the discretion of browser/OS. If you want force persistence and not live upto the mercy of browser/OS purge policy, use plugin sqlite as also recommended in ionic [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/storage).

Comment: "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^3.2.1", and "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0", this is my package.json

Comment: nice to know this stuff